# FragmentStatePagerAdapter: NullPointerException when changing dataset

Tags: android

I have a error when I try to update the datasource of my FragmentPagerAdapter, I have tried searching here but I don't find nothing similar

**Code from my Activity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    private List<Noticia> listaNoticias = new ArrayList<Noticia>();

// Set the adapters
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);        
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

// Get first page from JSON and show in the pager
    listaNoticias = Noticia.getPageFromJSON(1);
    ((ScreenSlidePagerAdapter) mPagerAdapter).setNoticias(listaNoticias);
    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Code from PageAdapter**

```
class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter 
 {
        private List<Noticia> noticias = new ArrayList<Noticia>();

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void setNoticias(List<Noticia> listaN)
        {
            noticias = new ArrayList<Noticia>(listaN);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) 
        {
            if(position==10)
            {
// Get the second page
                    noticias = Entry.addPageFromJSON(noticias, 2); // I manually checked the ArrayList and its content is OK
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            EntrySlidePageFragment fragmento = new EntrySlidePageFragment();
            fragmento.setFragment(noticias.get(position));

            return fragmento;   
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            return noticias.size();
        }

        public int getItemPosition(Object item) 
        {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }    
 }
```

**When I add the new content to the ArrayList the app stops working and I get these errors:**

```
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:119)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:829)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1044)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:242)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.completeScroll(ViewPager.java:1757)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1890)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:848)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Someone knows what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself using an older revision of **android-support-V4** packaged in 07/2012 and omitting **notifyDataSetChanged()**. Still do not know what was causing the error, maybe the new version has some bugs...